# Power BI. Add columns with previous dates metrics

Tags: powerbi

I need to display the difference of the average metric for the selected period with the indicator for the previous day, week and month.

I took an example from the article https://biprosto.ru/dax/previous.html

My formula looks like this

```
previous_day = CALCULATE (AVERAGE ('mydata' [position]), DATEADD ('calendar' [Date]. [Date], -1, DAY))
```

but empty values are returned.

[image: My dataset looks like this]

**Try with PREVIOUSDAY**
[image: Try with PREVIOUSDAY]

**Another try**
[image: Another try]

I also tried this option.
The date is shifted, but the values remain the same

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `.[Date]` at the end

```
previous_day = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('mydata'[position]), DATEADD('calendar'[Date], -1, DAY))
```

or you can also try

```
previous_day = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('mydata'[position]), PREVIOUSDAY('calendar'[Date]))
```

Comment: "Try removing the .[Date] at the end"
Have tried earlier, doesnt work

Other doesnt work too http://joxi.ru/a2XDxqjclMjM12

Comment: do you have any relationship between the `calendar` table and `mydata` table?

Comment: sure. It works, but now I have no change in previous_day, when date (previous_date) have been changed http://joxi.ru/D2PE4xNIBl5a7A

Comment: You should be using this as a measure instead of a column.

Comment: same http://joxi.ru/D2PE4xNIBlnWNA

Comment: I think I have problem with Calendar, but I dont know where,it`s just CALENDARAUTO()

Comment: This doesnt work too http://joxi.ru/82QMDkJUV6Xbk2

Comment: do you have a date column in your `mydata` table? You can try using that in the `PreviousDay` formula: `=CALCULATE(AVERAGE('mydata'[position]), PREVIOUSDAY('mydata'[Date]))` and create a Table visual with fields only from `mydata` table

Comment: It doesnt work too. I try to edit standart power bi measure, bot have no result too http://joxi.ru/Vrwn3BGtjb656A

Comment: screenshot shows you used the `DateAdd` function. Did you try using `PreviousDay` function? Also try using the formula as is for now, without any `IF` statements

Comment: Returns empty http://joxi.ru/krD486acgWDeyr, same without .[Date]

Comment: And no difference this way http://joxi.ru/4AkQv7XF0bzzQm cry

Comment: Try formatting your date column in `myTable` to "Date". Its probably in "Date/Time" right now. What format is it in right now?

Comment: Yes, problem with format. When I have no icon here http://joxi.ru/MAjJGynC1E5PYA and have calendar, it works. ut my formula now dont use calendar :D http://joxi.ru/J2by9RdCgBZKbm Dont understand it. Date now in date time format, no changes